# CakePHP Uploader: Change resize values depending on image dimension

Tags: cakephp, uploader

I am trying to implement Miles Johnsons excellent Uploader Component into my app. But here is the problem: Depending on the dimensions of the uploaded image, I need to change the resize dimensions.

I tried to modify the transformation in the callback:

```
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'nameCallback' => 'formatName',
                'tempDir' => TMP,
                'uploadDir' => UPLOADDIR,
                'finalPath' => '/img/photos/',
                'overwrite' => false,
                'stopSave' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'transforms' => array(
                    array(
                        'class' => 'exif',
                        'self' => true
                    ),
                    'image_sized' => array(
                        'class' => 'resize',
                        'nameCallback' => 'transformSizedNameCallback',
                        'width' => 1680,
                        'height' => 980,
                        'aspect' => true  
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'extension' => array(
                    'value' => array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
                    'error' => 'Nicht unterstütztes Dateiformat - bitte JPG- oder PNG-Datei hochladen.'
                ),
                'minHeight' => array(
                    'value' => 980,
                    'error' => 'Das Bild muss mindestens 980 Pixel hoch sein.'
                ),
                'minWidth' => array(
                    'value' => 980,
                    'error' => 'Das Bild muss mindestens 980 Pixel breit sein.'
                ),
                'required' => array(
                    'value' => true,
                    'error' => 'Bitte wählen Sie ein Bild aus.'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeTransform($options) {
        if($options['dbColumn'] == 'image_sized') {
            if($height > $width) {
                $options['width'] = 980;
                $options['height'] = 1680;
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
```

I am able to pinpoint the correct transform, but how do I access the dimensions of the image to be transformed inside of `beforeTransform`? Where do I get `$width` and `$height` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with it, but from looking at the code it seems like the only option you have at that point is using the `dbColumn` value to access the currently processed field data, something like

```
$file = $this->data[$this->alias][$options['dbColumn']];
```

Of course this requires the `dbColumn` value to match the input field name! If that's not the case, then you'll need an additional option that holds the field name and use that one instead.

Now `$file` is just the raw data, most probably a [**file upload array**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Assuming a single file, check `tmp_name` for its dimensions, either by yourself, or utilize the `Transite\File` class which can handle file upload arrays and exposes a method for retrieving the dimensions of a possible image:

```
$transitFile = new File($file);
$dimensions = $transitFile->dimensions();
```

https://github.com/milesj/transit/blob/1.5.1/src/Transit/File.php#L121

So finally you could do something like this:

```
public function beforeTransform($options) {
    if($options['dbColumn'] == 'image_sized') {
        $file = $this->data[$this->alias][$options['dbColumn']];
        $transitFile = new \Transit\File($file);
        $dimensions = $transitFile->dimensions();

        if($dimensions === null) {
            // not an image or something else gone wrong,
            // maybe throw an exception or wave your arms and call for help
        } elseif($dimensions['height'] > $dimensions['width']) {
            $options['width'] = 980;
            $options['height'] = 1680;
        }
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Please not that this is all untested example code.